# Javascript regex to allow specific characters in arabic

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write regex to allow specific characters or digits in Arabic language

i have this regex but it does match all arabic and english

```
   /^[-\sa-zA-Z,\u0600-\u06FF]+$/
```

i want to restrict it to write only `arabic letters` with `space` `(\s)` and dash `-`

For future use regex should be efficient to match provided group only for arabic langauge it could be

1. Arabic letters with space
2. Arabic letters with digits only
3. Arabic letters with space and digits

Comment: So, remove `a-zA-Z,`, keep `^[-\s\u0600-\u06FF]+$`. Isn't that evident? If you want to add digits, add `0-9` (or whatever digit range you need).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i guess OP needs a common regex which could work on both langs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex also match the arabic comma it should accept only arabic letters with space or dash see your doesnt work here [link](https://regex101.com/r/mE7uF8/1)

Comment: @Jai i only wants above requirement to fill with regex

Comment: What about `^[-\s\u0621-\u064A]+$`? With Arabic numbers: `^[-\s\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669]+$`

Comment: Or (as I see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Character_table), there are more letters and even some extended digits): `/^[-\s\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u06F0-\u06F9]+$/` (where `\u06F0-\u06F9` stands for extended digits and `\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF` stand for - I think - all the letters).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
/^[-\s\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0‌6F0-\u06F9]+$/
```

Here, `\u06F0-\u06F9` range stands for extended digits and `\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF` stand for all letters.

See legend (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Character_table)) (**adjust as you see fit** using the table below):

[image]